# How to efficienly debug in Lua?

Tags: c, debugging, lua

I am totally new in Lua (just start 2 days ago). Now I want to know some efficient debug ways in Lua. I have read through the Debug library of Lua but I am wondering whether it is efficient (probably I am too new to find the cool part of it.)

I used python before and really like the command pdb.set_trace(), by which I can stop at the point I like and check the executed codes. Is there any similar command in Lua? By the way, I run Lua script on cygwin.

And, if I use C API to call Lua functions, and I debug it in eclipse, can I just set breakpoint as I do to pure C codes?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Try to google "zero brain lua" ;-)

Comment: Thanks! It seems an eclipse specially for Lua :D